# making jquery ui tabs work on appended elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, append, jquery-ui-tabs

I want to use the `.tabs` effect (customised a little) on some `append()` -ed HTML like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.get('/featured-slider.php', function(data) {
    $('#wrapper').append(data);
  });

  $('#featured-slider').tabs({fx:{opacity: 
       "toggle"}}).tabs("rotate", 5000, true);
});
```

If the contents of `featured-slider.php` are already in the file (that is to say I do not `.get()` at all) the tabs effect works great. However, if I try to `append()` the HTML (like the code above) it does not work.

Does anyone know how to make it work?

Comment: can you add a bit details i.e. your html code and what exactly are you trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving your .tabs invocation to the .get callback:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get('/featured-slider.php', function(data) {
        $('#wrapper').append(data);
        $('#featured-slider').tabs({fx:{opacity: "toggle"}}).tabs("rotate", 5000, true);
    });
});
```